# How can click on a javascript show link programatically with vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to develop a new feature for our vb.net order entry system. At the moment I provide an assisted paypal login which loops through transactions and copies the transactions. My program then looks at this data and copies it into text boxes. The operator then approves and saves the record.

***EDIT: I need to see the transaction in PayPal.***

So my code uses `IHTMLFormElement` and loops round form elements and adds values. However I only really use this to log in to paypal. See my code...

```
Dim theObject As Object = Nothing
theObject = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_login-run"

WebBrowPayPal.AxWebBrowser1.Navigate2(theObject)

While WebBrowPayPal.AxWebBrowser1.ReadyState <> 
   tagREADYSTATE.READYSTATE_COMPLETE
  Application.DoEvents()
End While

Dim HtmlDoc As IHTMLDocument2 = CType(WebBrowPayPal.AxWebBrowser1.Document, 
    IHTMLDocument2)
Dim FormCol As IHTMLElementCollection = HtmlDoc.forms

Dim iForms As Integer = FormCol.length
Dim i As Integer
Dim x As Integer
For i = 0 To iForms - 1
 Dim oForm As IHTMLFormElement = CType(FormCol.item(CType(i, Object), 
     CType(i, Object)), IHTMLFormElement)

 For x = 0 To oForm.length - 1
  If oForm.elements(x).tagname = "INPUT" Then 
    If oForm.elements(x).name = "login_email" Then
      oForm.elements(x).value = "PayPal@mydomain.com"
    End If

    If oForm.elements(x).name = "login_password" Then
     oForm.elements(x).value = "mypassword"
    End If

    If oForm.elements(x).type = "submit" Or _
       oForm.elements(x).type = "SUBMIT" Then
      oForm.elements(x).click()
    End If
  End If 
 Next
Next i
```

I'm now trying this page
https://www.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_history&nav=0.3.0

Which is the history page, which allows you to search on the paypal transaction id.
Unfortunately you need to click on 'find a transaction' which then uses some javascript to shows the post fields. So the problem is that the fields I need to use are hidden.

How can I click on this javascript link in code ?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the Paypal API for this?

Comment: @ Jules - You should really use Paypal APIs.

Comment: I need to see the transaction within paypal!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help but you might want to try executing the script (which fires when you're clicking "Find a transaction") directly using `IHTMLDocument2.write` method:

```
Dim HtmlDoc As IHTMLDocument2 = CType(WebBrowPayPal.AxWebBrowser1.Document, 
  IHTMLDocument2)
HtmlDoc.write("<script>[Search button event handler]</script>")
```

**UPDATE**

I managed to get it working. Here is a form `Load` event handler (WinForms) that causes the Web Browser control to load http://www.google.com and then clicks "I'm feeling lucky" button:

```
    Imports mshtml

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim clicked As Boolean = False
        Dim doc As IHTMLDocument2 = Nothing
        Dim form As IHTMLFormElement = Nothing
        Dim input As HTMLInputElement = Nothing
        Dim forms As IHTMLElementCollection = Nothing

        AxWebBrowser1.Navigate2("http://www.google.com")

        While AxWebBrowser1.ReadyState <> SHDocVw.tagREADYSTATE.READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            Application.DoEvents()
        End While

        doc = CType(AxWebBrowser1.Document, IHTMLDocument2)

        For i As Integer = 0 To doc.forms.length - 1
            form = CType(doc.forms.item(i, i), IHTMLFormElement)

            For j As Integer = 0 To form.length - 1
                If TypeOf (form.elements(j)) Is HTMLInputElement Then
                    input = CType(form.elements(j), HTMLInputElement)

                    If String.Compare(input.name, "btnI", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) = 0 Then
                        input.click()
                        clicked = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            Next

            If clicked Then
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

If you need to click on a link then just change `HTMLInputElement` to `HTMLLinkElement` (in declaration and cast operation).

I suppose you're not using WinForms but if you do so, I'd suggest you to switch to the [.NET version of the WebBrowser control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx).

Hope this will help you.

-- Pavel

Comment: I'm not sure if this would work, also I'm not sure what the search button handler is.

Comment: @Jules: Sorry, I don't have a valid PayPal account so I can't really reproduce your problem. But I hope that my answer pointed you to the right direction.